# Lubuntu semi-random crashes

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, crash

Since I installed Lubuntu as my main OS (removed Windows which worked fine for years) I get random crashes. Sometimes before the crash I get visual artifacts (for example when moving a window) but most times it straight up crashes. This results in a black screen and the audio crashing on the way it loops the last second forever.
The crash folder is empty.
I have tried disabling my overclock and XMP and unpluging and plugging back the GPU cables but nothing helped. I also ran update and upgrade.
The crashes sometimes continually happen at the loading screen but sometimes occur much later.

EDIT: This bug is not specific to Lubuntu as it is caused by the AMD dpm
I have an AMD GPU and an intel CPU and am running Lubunu 19.04

Comment: It reads like hardware issues to me, esp. if you were overclocking.  I would firstly check your ram (ie. run memtest a couple of times over), then do a cap-check of your motherboard etc... (ie. it reads like hardware issues to me).  You could also boot a 'live' system (I'd suggest something that is not Lubuntu, not even the same release of your Lubuntu) and validate your system using a different environment - but I'd be looking at your hardware.

Comment: I tried reverting the overclock (and I ran memtest 86 when I got the PC) Furthermore it ran stable on windows for years. I do not have a multi meter, so I don't think I can do a cap check (also the massive heat sink is covering most of the motherboard). I tried Ubuntu once before and it was fine. I will try installing it again but it will take a while since I will need to do it through Lubuntu (without it crashing half way through)

Comment: Overclocking puts extra strain on components and so shortens the life - it was this I was thinking about (thus working for years only proves age & thus increases signifance of your comment). A cap-check requires only reasonable eye-sight (but is hardware related and off-topic on this site).  Before re-installing Lubuntu please use `check disc for defects* as seen in the manual (top picture of https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html to ensure download of ISO & write-to-media was flawless)

Comment: Thanks, I will try a cap-check. I doubt it happened exacely when I installed lubuntu but will try. I checked the disc for defects but will do it again before installing Ubuntu just in case.

Comment: UPDATE: memtest passed without a problem but I am getting the same issues on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `radeon.dpm=0`to the GRUB menu, what this does is disables the "dynamic power management" in your GPU.

The top answer of this thread tells how to edit boot options better than I could so I will just link it here:
[How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)